# Calling StreetView in IPhone Maps App from External Application

Tags: iphone, google-street-view

I'm trying to make an external call to the google maps application on the iphone from my application and send it straight to "streetview" mode from two lat, lon coordinates.  I've tried a variety of combinations, but each one just sends me to the safari browser on the iPhone and not to the maps application.

Here is one of those tries:

```
NSString * latlonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&layer=c&cbll=%@,%@&cbp=12,261.11,,0,5", lat, long];
```

For the record, I've successfully been able to call the external maps application to get driving directions.

Has anyone been successful in calling street view mode from an external app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Check the Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894) for all available options for map links.

Comment: thats the link i was looking for thanks.  yep -- doesn't look possible and very disappointing -- and doesn't really make sense -- the capability is already built in.....